# do anybody know jquery plugin of slideshow in which different delay time for each slide can be set?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow

i want to set different delay time for different slides those will be generated dynamically .
do you know some jquery plugin or any other code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found jquery.cycle

and customize it like this

i made the  name of the images for the time i want to set for them like:
3000.gif
15000.gif

and then set options.timeout on event before of plugin.

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({

    fx: 'fade',     
    timeout : '3000',
  before: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options) {

  var nextFileName = arrSrc[(arrSrc.length-1)].split('.')[0];       

       options.timeout = nextFileName; 


  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple slideshows using cycle plugin, then you can initialize the function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#slideshow1').cycle({fx: 'fade',delay:   -2000});
   $('#slideshow2').cycle({fx: 'fade',delay:   -1000 });
});
```